# angular - read property name from JSON as column name and show another property value in the column

Tags: json, angular

I have json file in a structure (showing one of its objects) as

```
[
...
{
        "Tag": "YearOfOperation",
        "Type": 9,
        "Value": "2018"
    }
...
]
```

on html template I have a table. On table's "Year Of Operation" row , I want to display "2018". I am trying to iterate over json (i.e find by row/tag name) and display display "Value" of the json. In html template, I want to have something like:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td> Year Of Operation </td> // row name is hard coded. it doesn't depend on json
<td> display json "Value" where "Tag"=="YearOfOperation" </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

app.component.ts

```
public productData: any;


ngOnInit() {
            this.getJSON().subscribe(res => {
                this.productData = JSON.parse(res);
            })
        }

public getJSON(): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get('./images/output_test.json')
            .pipe(
                map(res => res)
            )
        // .catch((error:any) => console.log(error));

    }
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you elobarate on the question. What do you mean by i have to find ? When do you want to find ?. Is it when the dropdown is selcted .. How ?

Comment: Please add some more context and code snippets. As it sits now, this question is very unclear, at least for me ;)

Comment: sorry for that, I have added some more details :)

Comment: Still not enough information. How does your template look like? Best would be if you create a Stackblitz, there you also make sure you have enough code to reproduce and therefore for us to debug :) Also you don't need to parse the response you get from http request, it's already JSON.

Comment: does your json has multiple value object array or one ?

Comment: @Exterminator multiple

Comment: I am trying to avoid {{ getRowName("YearOfOperation") }} on my html and iterate over json on my app.component.ts

Comment: I would just make a copy of that array and in the copy make it manageable for iteration... this is a table, so no values are being changed. If the customer wants the data to look like that. Let them, but do what you want with the copy (neccessarily no need to use a copy unless you need the original array) :)

Answer (score 0):

If your JSON is something like below and i understood your question correctly, then this is what should work for you:

app.json

```
[
  { "Tag":"Location", "type": 9, "Value":"Europe" },
  { "Tag":"Location", "type": 10, "Value":"US" },
  { "Tag":"YearOfOperation", "type": 9, "Value":"2016" },
  { "Tag":"YearOfOperation", "type": 10, "Value":"2018" },
  { "Tag":"TaxId", "type": 9, "Value":"txn123" },
  { "Tag":"TaxId", "type": 10, "Value":"txn124" }
]
```

app.component.html

```
<table>
  <thead><tr><th>Location</th><th>Year Of Operation</th><th>Tax ID</th></tr></thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let product of products">
      <td *ngIf="product?.Tag === 'Location'; else blankValue">{{product?.Value}}</td>
      <td *ngIf="product?.Tag === 'YearOfOperation'; else blankValue">{{product?.Value}}</td>
      <td *ngIf="product?.Tag === 'TaxId'; else blankValue">{{product?.Value}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<ng-template #blankValue><td></td></ng-template>
```

app.component.ts

```
public products: any;

ngOnInit() {
    this.getJSON().subscribe(res => {
      this.products = <Array<{}>>res;
    })
}

public getJSON(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get('./images/output_test.json')
    .pipe(
      map(res => res),
      catchError((error) => { console.error(error); return error;})
    );
}
```

app.component.css

```
th {
    padding:10px;
    border:1px solid black;
}

td {
    padding:10px;
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but this won't fit for my case as rows and columns are hard coded. For a specific column I should display specific item of the json.

Comment: @user3506588 I updated my answer according to your latest update. please check.